# PHP Version 5.2.14 / Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_FUNCTION, expecting ')'

Tags: php, parsing, parse-error

I have a certain piece of code that I'm trying to use with PHP Version 5.2.14 . Is it incompatible?? I run the following,

```
jailshell-3.2$ php -l /XYZ/functions.php
```

And it gives:

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_FUNCTION, expecting ')' in /XYZ/functions.php on line 2115
>       Errors parsing /XYZ/functions.php

The code is:

```
2114    $range = array_map(
2115                function (DatePeriod $p) use ($vt2) {
2116               $res = array();
```

Answer (score 7):

Your code uses [`anonymous functions`](http://php.net/manual/en/functions.anonymous.php) which were supported in PHP 5.3. So, you need PHP 5.3 to get it to working. Upgrade your server's PHP installation.

*Anonymous functions, also known as closures, allow the creation of functions which have no specified name.*

Answer (score 4):

You are using [anonymous functions](http://php.net/manual/en/functions.anonymous.php) which are available since **PHP 5.3.0**.

To resolve this you can upgrade your PHP as suggested in other answer.

Alternatively you can define the function outside `array_map` and then use that function name in the call to `array_map`

Answer (score 3):

From the php manual on [Anonymous Functions](http://php.net/manual/en/functions.anonymous.php):

> Note: Anonymous functions are available since PHP 5.3.0.

prior to 5.3.0, do it like this:

```
$range = array_map( "name_of_function_to_call", $myArray );
```

Answer (score 1):

I think the lambda style function is not yet implemented in 5.2

use [create_function](http://php.net/manual/en/function.create-function.php) or just create the function and pass it the [function name in array_map](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php).