# syntax error, unexpected T_FUNCTION, expecting ')'

Tags: php, ajax

hi i have purchased theme but i think there is bug in contact form submission. theme use ajax to submit contact form.

link of contact form `http://192.185.83.133/~lbrisas/TRY/ibrisas/contact.html`

when you fill complete form and submit i will submit form using jquery ajax to contact.php file and here is code for the contact.php

code

```
<?php

    spl_autoload_register(function($class_name){
        $file_name = str_replace('\\', '/', $class_name);
        $file_name = str_replace('_', '/', $file_name);
        $file = dirname(__FILE__) . "/lib/$file_name.php";
        if(is_file($file)) include $file;
    });

    use HybridLogic\Validation\Validator;
    use HybridLogic\Validation\Rule;

    $CONFIG = array(
        /* Mail Options */
        'mail_send_to'      =>  'vishalnthoriya@gmail.com', 
        'mail_contents'     =>  'mail-content.php', 
        'mail_failed_msg'   =>  'An unknown error has occured', 

        /* Notification Messages */
        'form_errors_msg'   =>  '<h4>The following errors were encountered</h4><ul><li>%s</li></ul>', 
        'form_invalid_msg'  =>  'The form is invalid', 
        'form_success_msg'  =>  '<h4>Thank you</h4>Your message has been sent, we\'ll get back to you shortly :)'
    );

    function createFormMessage( $formdata )
    {
        global $CONFIG;

        ob_start();

        extract($formdata);
        include $CONFIG['mail_contents'];

        return ob_get_clean();
    }

    function cleanInput($input) {
        $search = array(
            '@<script[^>]*?>.*?</script>@si',   // Strip out javascript
            '@<[\/\!]*?[^<>]*?>@si',            // Strip out HTML tags
            '@<style[^>]*?>.*?</style>@siU',    // Strip style tags properly
            '@<![\s\S]*?--[ \t\n\r]*>@'         // Strip multi-line comments
        );

        $output = preg_replace($search, '', $input);
        return $output;
    }

    function sanitize($input) {
        if (is_array($input)) {
            foreach($input as $var=>$val) {
                $output[$var] = sanitize($val);
            }
        }
        else {
            if (get_magic_quotes_gpc()) {
                $input = stripslashes($input);
            }
            $input  = cleanInput($input);
            $output = $input;
        }
        return $output;
    }

    $formdata = sanitize( $_POST['ContactForm'] );
    $response = array();
    $validator = new Validator();
    $validator
        ->set_label('name', 'Name')
        ->set_label('email', 'Email')
        ->set_label('subject', 'Subject')
        ->set_label('comment', 'Comment')
        ->add_filter('name', 'trim')
        ->add_filter('email', 'trim')
        ->add_filter('email', 'strtolower')
        ->add_filter('subject', 'trim')
        ->add_rule('name', new Rule\NotEmpty())
        ->add_rule('email', new Rule\NotEmpty())
        ->add_rule('email', new Rule\Email())
        ->add_rule('subject', new Rule\NotEmpty())
        ->add_rule('comment', new Rule\NotEmpty());

    if( $validator->is_valid( $formdata ) )
    {
        include 'lib/swiftmail/swift_required.php';

        $transport = Swift_MailTransport::newInstance();
        $mailer = Swift_Mailer::newInstance($transport);

        $body = createFormMessage($formdata);

        $message = Swift_Message::newInstance();
        $message
            ->setSubject($formdata['subject'])
            ->setFrom($formdata['email'])
            ->setTo($CONFIG['mail_send_to'])
            ->setBody($body, 'text/html');

        if( !$mailer->send($message) ) {
            $response['success'] = false;
            $response['message'] = $CONFIG['mail_failed_msg'];
        } else {
            $response['success'] = true;
            $response['message'] = $CONFIG['form_success_msg'];
        }
    } else {
        $response = array( 'success'=>false, 'message'=>sprintf($CONFIG['form_errors_msg'], implode('</li><li>', $validator->get_errors() ) ) );
    }

    echo json_encode($response);
?>
```

here is error
:Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_FUNCTION, expecting ')' in /home/lbrisas/public_html/TRY/ibrisas/php/contact.php on line 3

thanks in advance

Comment: What version of PHP are you using? Anonymous functions are supported in 5.3+

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP Version 5.2.14 / Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T\_FUNCTION, expecting ')'](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3723748/php-version-5-2-14-parse-error-syntax-error-unexpected-t-function-expecting)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change the way of calling function since anonymous functions are not supported in your PHP version:

```
function stack_2145($class_name)
{
    $file_name = str_replace('\\', '/', $class_name);
    $file_name = str_replace('_', '/', $file_name);
    $file = dirname(__FILE__) . "/lib/$file_name.php";
    if(is_file($file)) include $file;
}
spl_autoload_register("stack_2145");
```

Comment: That won't be enough, just look at the lines right below that one. The code also uses namespaces and probably other modern PHP  features.

Answer (score 4):

You need to upgrade to PHP 5.3 for anonymous function support.

Answer (score -2):

Instead of using

```
spl_autoload_register($class_name) {
// your code
}
```

Try using this

```
function __autoload($class_name) {
// your code
}
```

Comment: HI thanks for replay but  problem was with PHP version as mention in above two replies.

Thanks